# iPhone icon - Red # indicators

Tags: iphone, icons, notifications

How do you implement the red number indicators (like the email count notification)?

Comment: You should really accept an answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 12):

What you are looking for is the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` property which is a property of `UIApplication`.

To set the badge, from anywhere in your app, use:

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1; // set to any integer
```

To remove the badge, set the property to 0.

[Documentation on Apple Developer Website](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/applicationIconBadgeNumber)

Comment: thanks! i suppose default iphone apps, such as email, can set these badge counts even when the app isnt running (or the app runs silently in the background). because they get badge updates even when they're not open.

Comment: Yes, but you can use the push notification service to push badge updates over the air. Without the PNS, you need to update the application badge when your application launches.

Comment: BTW, if this answers your question, please don't forget to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a "badge".

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 2;
```

EDIT: removed SetApplicationBadge

Comment: I'm still unsure where you are getting this `setApplicationBadge` method from.